# PHP: 404 header not working on HTTPS site - returns blank page instead of default not found page

Tags: php, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

I have a wildcard certificate for, lets call it *.example.com and I've set up a virtual host for *.example.com in the Apache (for both HTTPS and non-HTTPS traffic).

Been messing around with some 404 response headers, but I seem to have a problem, so I made a simple test case:

In the virtaul host I rewrite all traffic to index.php:

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php [QSA]
```

And in `index.php` I return a 404 header:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
exit();
```

I don't do anything else but that, so no `ErrorDocument` set or similar.

Dump of headers returned by the server (user `file_get_contents("https://test.example.com");` and `print_r($http_response_header);` from another PHP file:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
    [1] => Date: Mon, 08 Oct 2012 12:41:28 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
    [3] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
    [4] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
    [5] => Content-Length: 57
    [6] => Connection: close
    [7] => Content-Type: text/html
)
```

If I then enter the HTTP site on any subdomain/any path the browser will correctly show the default not found page, but if I use HTTPS the browser will instead show a blank page (except in IE which will correctly(?) show the not found page).

`header("Status: 404 Not Found");` does not work either.

This can't be right can it? Is there something I'm missing here - some kind of limitations on 404 headers and wildcard certificates maybe?

**Update by request of Hakre**

Headers dumped from `headers_list()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
)
```

It seems that the server completely ignores adding my 404 header, regardless of using any of these ways of writing the header:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Other headers such as `header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");` works properly.

Comment: The 404 not found header is somewhat special in PHP, you find the details outlined in the documentation of the PHP [`header` function](http://php.net/header). It also has some explanations about the `Status:` header and for what it is used for. Also in your header-dump it is not clear to which header-calls it relates to. What you write there does not seem to be correct, the code example does not match with the dump. And stop at the most possible point of failure: Not SSL, just not sending the right header. If you use a current PHP you have http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Comment: My bad, I dumped the request where I had both `header("Status: 404 Not Found");` and `header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");`. This is corrected now and I've also added a segment with headers dumped using `headers_list();`

Comment: Using something like FireBug, what headers does the browser recieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
```

Even if you are using HTTPS, you should return:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php how is using `$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I thought it would set the value to HTTPS not HTTP/1.X